# How to query all data where `created` today (from 00h:00m:00s to now) in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

How to query all data where `created` is today (from 00h:00m:00s to now) in mongoose?

```
{
  "user": ObjectId("52fe173148ee58a0180c1d77"),
  "caption": "aaaa",
  "created": ISODate("2014-02-14T16:04:57.98Z"),
  "__v": NumberInt(0)
}

{
  "user": ObjectId("52fe173148ee58a0180c1d77"),
  "caption": bbb",
  "created": ISODate("2014-02-14T14:10:27.986Z"),
  "__v": NumberInt(0)
}
```

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward.  What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: +1.  What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni, `Db.find().when({'created':'today'}).exec(function(err, result) {console.log(result)})`. Does mongoose have some kind of query like this?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, Is there some kind of query like: Db.find({"created_on": {"$gte": yesterday}})?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create a `Date` object that contains the start of today and then use that in the query:

```js
var now = new Date();
var startOfToday = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
MyModel.find({created_on: {$gte: startOfToday}}, function (err, docs) { ... });
```

Comment: This is so great!. If I want to add more Conditions for this query like this: `MyModel.find({'user':some_id}).where('created_on').gt(startOfToday) .exec(function (err, docs) { ... });`. Is that ok?. I have tried, but not work, may be I am wrong in some things

Comment: @user3044147 Yes, you can add more conditions like that.  Post a new question with the details if you can't get it working.